# How can we put a varying packet error rate in omnet++

Tags: omnet++

Is there a way to put a varying PER(packet error rate) in the omnet.ini file for a single simulation? I know to simulate for different simulations and compare the graph, but I want one simulation which varies PER. Generally, we put the PER in the ini file as in percentage and have a constant PER but I want is varying one between 1% to 50%.

```
PER = 0.5 #Generally we do like this to show 50% PER
PER= #(0.1 to 0.5) #I need something like this
```

Hope I am clear.

Comment: How often the value of PER is read in your code, i.e. how often `per = par("PER")` is called?

Comment: I do not have the exact answer to that, but I am using a simple TCPwindowscale example of the INET4 framework. I think the .ini file will run once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways of achieving your goal.
**Method 1**

1. In NED declare PER parameter with `volatile`:

   ```
    parameters:
      volatile double PER;
   ```
2. In `omnetpp.ini` use a random distribution, for example a uniform distribution:

   ```
   **.somemodule.PER = uniform(0.01, 0.50)
   ```
3. In C++ code of your module use `par("PER")` in every place where that value is read.

Thanks to `volatile` every time that parameter is read, a new random value is chosen. Reference: [OMNeT++ Simulation Manual](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:ned-lang:volatile)

---

**Method 2**

1. In NED declare two parameters:

   ```
    parameters:
      double minPER;
      double maxPER;
   ```
2. In `omnetpp.ini` set the values of these parameters:

   ```
    **.somemodule.minPER = 0.01
    **.somemodule.maxPER = 0.50
   ```
3. In `initialize()` of your C++ class read these parameters, e.g.:

   ```
    minPER = par("minPER");
    maxPER = par("maxPER");
   ```
4. In C++ in the place where PER value is necessary generate the current value using a random distribution, for example:

   ```
   double per = uniform(minPER, maxPER);
   ```

Comment: Could you tell where the should be .cc file per variable is used because I did not make any changes to INET TCP framework?

Comment: In OMNeT++ the C++ class for simple module called `Foo` by default is called `Foo`, too. Moreover, the C++ may be called Foo.h/Foo.cc. So look for the C++ file that has the same name as the name of the simple module in which PER is defined.